# How to get rid of $outer reference in path dependent class

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I'd like to use path dependent types for static type checks. But naive implementation unfortunately introduce significant overhead: each inner class exemplar stores link to the enclosing object in the `$outer` field.

*example*:

```
class A() {
  case class B(x : Int)
}
```

*part of `javap` output on the compiled class*:

```
$ javap -private A\$B.class 
Compiled from "Example.scala"
public class example.A$B implements scala.Product,scala.Serializable {
  private final int x;
  public final example.A $outer;
```

How can I enjoy static checks without runtime overhead?